# What is the chance that there is atleast one water molecule in a given volume of space

Tags: water

If you imagine a single cubic meter, and place it anywhere in space, in any orientation and take any two opposite faces of the imaginary cube, and stretch them to both edges of the universe; what is the probability of having atleast one water molecule in this volume?

[image: problem visualisation]

I assume that if space is as unimaginably large as I think it is, surely the probability to have atleast one water molecule must approach 100% if the volume is large enough, but how large would a volume need to be to contain atleast 1 water molecule on average (if placed anywhere in the universe)?

Comment: This question is probably on-topic in [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/), but it's not about the *exploration of space* since "anywhere in space" is way beyond what we can explore. I'd say let this be closed and perhaps migrated there, but in the mean time perhaps you should ask a more limited question about the distribution of water in interstellar space. Since water is such an incredibly sticky molecule, I think you'll be looking for [interstellar ice particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_ice) rather than isolated molecules

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cool question! Probably Physics or Astronomy SE would provide a better answer, but for a first-order fermi approximation, my understanding is that Ewine F. van Dishoeck (Leiden Observatory, Leiden University)'s 2011 article [Water In Space](http://dx.doi.org/10.1051/epn/2011105) (direct to PDF [here](https://www.europhysicsnews.org/articles/epn/pdf/2011/01/epn2011421p26.pdf)) reports that the ratio of water vapor molecules to H in inter*galactic* space is between 10^-4 and 10^-9. A general figure for the density of intergalactic space is 1 atom per cubic centimeter. Given that such a 1 square meter slice through the observable universe would be 10^26 meters long, it seems most likely that there will *always* be a molecule of water in such a chunk, and most probably much more.

Using the lower bound from the paper above, one might expect there to be one water molecule in a volume of only a few thousand cubic meters.

It would be interesting to run the numbers on the odds that your chunk happens to slice through one of the many structures in space that  aggregate water, like the Quasar APM 08279+5255.

Comment: cool answer, cool paper! :-)